Can you do a IFR flight in a uncontrolled space in a helicopter?
Can you do a IFR flight from point A to point B (both within an uncontrolled airspace) in IMC in a helicopter?
Would there be a minimum altitude?

IFR in uncontrolled airspace (classes F and G) does not require a clearance. You still have to fly whatever the legal minimum altitudes are. In the US, that's 1000 feet above the tallest obstacle within 4 nautical miles (2000 feet in designated mountainous areas). Since controlled airspace starts 1200 AGL at the highest through the vast majority of the lower 48 and obstructions aren't even depicted on sectionals if they're shorter 200 feet AGL, this makes uncontrolled IFR flight impossible as a practical matter. The maximum altitude to stay in class G is less than the minimum altitudes for obstacle clearance throughout much of the US, and they are very, very close to each other everywhere else.

The defining feature of uncontrolled airspace is that you are allowed to fly IFR without a clearance. It doesn't matter what type of aircraft you're using; in uncontrolled airspace your scenario is legal.
Minimum altitude depends on the local regulations; in the usa that's faa-regulations 14 CFR 91.177, which applies equally in controlled and in uncontrolled airspace. Of course in the USA you would be extremely hard-pressed to comply with 91.177 while remaining entirely within uncontrolled airspace.
Note that by "uncontrolled airspace" we mean specifically Class F and Class G airspace. VFR pilots often refer to Class E airspace as "uncontrolled" because there is no ATC communication or clearance requirement for VFR aircraft in Class E, but this is not the case for IFR aircraft.

I see, and what would be the minimum visibility in USA to do a flight like this?

In-flight, minimum visibility is 0SM. For takeoff from a civil airport, 1/2SM per 91.175(f)(2)(iii), unless otherwise specified for that airport. But that's for an air carrier or similar operation... for a non-air-carrier operation, there are no prescribed takeoff minimums (i.e. a zero-zero takeoff is legal).

Oh wow no minimum for a non carrier. But would that be even safe? What would you do if for example right after you takeoff (let's say at 100 feet), you lose engine power and you have to put it down with such low visibility?

When it comes to regulations, what is legal may not be safe (and to a far lesser extent, what is safe may not be legal).

yeah that's right.
